# Need to compare previous day date type to integer value

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I have a requirement where I need to generate a report twice a month.

I came up with logic below ... the challenging part is to set the default start date to -16 or -15 depending on previous day.

For example, if previous date day part is = 31 then take -16 as startdate else take -15.

```
=IIF((datepart("dd",-1,today()))=31,dateserial(year(now()),month(now()),"1").adddays(-16), dateserial(year(now()),month(now()),"1").adddays(-15) )
```

I have been trying the above expression for it and getting the Error.

> [rsCompilerErrorInExpression]  The Value expression for the report
>   parameter ‘startdate’ contains an error: [BC30311] Value of type
>   'Date' cannot be converted to 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.FirstDayOfWeek'.

Answer (score 1):

How about this instead?

```
=DateAdd("d",IIF(Day(Dateadd("d",-1,Today()))=31,-16,-15),Today())
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jerry Ritcey , that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
=IIF(Day(DateAdd("d",-1,Today()))=31,dateserial(year(now()),month(now()),"1").adddays(-16), dateserial(year(now()),month(now()),"1").adddays(-15) )
```

Comment: Thank you so much Kashif Qureshi for the help, Its working perfectly now. Both the snippets yours and Mr Jerry Ritcey's snippet are holding good for this requirement.